# How can I find the approximate locations of solutions of $a^x\ln(a)+b^x\ln(b)+c^x\ln(c)=0$ provided that $a+b+c=3$ and $a,b,c$ are not all equal?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I need to sketch a rough graph of  $f(x)=a^x+b^x+c^x$ provided that  $a+b+c=3$ and $a,b,c$ are not all equal.
$$f'(x)=a^x\ln(a)+b^x\ln(b)+c^x\ln(c)$$

How can I find the approximate locations of solutions of
$$a^x\ln(a)+b^x\ln(b)+c^x\ln(c)=0$$
I would then use this to find the maxima,minima and points of inflections of the curve.

I took the function $f(x)=a^x+b^x+c^x$

I figured there must be one solution in $x∈(0,1)$ by Rolle's theorem because $f(0)=f(1)=3$ and the function is continuous.

I don't know how to find any other solutions if any. By using a graphical calculator to sketch some curves, it seems like there are no other such points. If this is true how can I prove it?

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: Numerical approximations for solutions of $f'(x)=0$ can be found by many CAS (computer algebra systems). For instance pari/gp or sage. We need special values of $a,b,c$ for this.  Which values should be used?

Comment: @dan_fulea I don't know what values of a,b,c to use, which is why I am attempting to sketch a rough graph. And since this is a potential exam question, where I won't have access to such systems, there should be a way to assess locations of such roots without a CAS. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @ Théophile  Oh...right. Thanks! I'll correct it straight away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the next derivative,
$$f''(x) = a^x(\ln a)^2 + b^x(\ln b)^2 + c^x(\ln c)^2 > 0.$$
Therefore there are no points of inflexion, and there is a unique minimum for some $x \in (0,1)$. Indeed, experimenting with a graphing calculator shows that the minimum is almost always close to $1/2$.